# How can i declare a function in a veriable (mySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have

--> SET @Anzahl = 10;

But i want something like that:

--> SET @Anzahl = COUNT(table.columnID);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SET @Anzahl = (SELECT COUNT(table.columnID) FROM YOURTABLE);

Answer (score 1):

You can use

**SELECT INTO** like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(table.columnID) INTO @Anzahl FROM YOURTABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT`:

```
SELECT @Anzahl := count(*)
FROM table t;
```

After all, you need a query for `COUNT(*)` to work.